# Get non-overlapping dates ranges for prices history data

Tags: sql-server

Let's assume that I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PricesHist]
(
   [Product] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
   [Price] [float] NOT NULL,
   [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
)


INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D2C00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D2C00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D2D00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D2D00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 2.5, CAST(0x00009D2E00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D2E00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D3000000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3000000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D3100000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3100000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D3400000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3400000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 2.5, CAST(0x00009D3500000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3500000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D3600000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D3700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D3800000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3800000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D3A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3A00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D3B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3B00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 2.5, CAST(0x00009D3C00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3C00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D3D00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3D00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D3E00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3E00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D3F00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D3F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D4100000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D4100000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D4200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D4200000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 2.5, CAST(0x00009D4300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D4300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D4400000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D4400000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D4500000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D4500000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D4600000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D4600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 4.9, CAST(0x00009D4800000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D4800000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PricesHist] ([Product], [Price], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (N'Apples', 2.5, CAST(0x00009D4A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009D4A00000000 AS DateTime))
```

As you can see, there are two prices on that month for Apples. 4.90 and 2.50.
In order to tidy this table up, I need to get this information as a date range rather than a row per day as it currently is.

I can obviously do this with Min and Max aggregates easily but the ranges overlap and other business code expect non-overlapping ranges.
I also tried to achieve this with self joins and row_number(), but without much success...

Here is what I'm trying to achieve as the output:

```
Product | StartDate   |  EndDate    | Price
-------------------------------------------
Apples  | 01 Mar 2010 | 02 Mar 2010 | 4.90
Apples  | 03 Mar 2010 | 03 Mar 2010 | 2.50
Apples  | 05 Mar 2010 | 09 Mar 2010 | 4.90
Apples  | 10 Mar 2010 | 10 Mar 2010 | 2.50
Apples  | 11 Mar 2010 | 16 Mar 2010 | 4.90
Apples  | 17 Mar 2010 | 17 Mar 2010 | 2.50
Apples  | 18 Mar 2010 | 23 Mar 2010 | 4.90
Apples  | 24 Mar 2010 | 24 Mar 2010 | 2.50
Apples  | 25 Mar 2010 | 30 Mar 2010 | 4.90
Apples  | 31 Mar 2010 | 31 Mar 2010 | 2.50
```

What would please be the best approach to get this done?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: It would be easiest to do this as either a stored procedure or put the logic into your application.

Comment: This is legacy data from a previous import from a previous software. I just need it to tidy up this table as it takes way too many records (one row per day and product).

Comment: Why is there no row for Mar 4th, but there are for the 7th and 8th?

Comment: Sorry, it is because the shop was closed on the 4th.

Comment: Ok, but why do you have other non-existent dates covered? It seems inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you pretty close. Once you determine how you want to handle missing dates, you can adjust it appropriately:

```
SELECT
    SD.Product,
    SD.Price,
    SD.StartDate,
    MAX(ED.EndDate) AS EndDate
FROM
    dbo.PricesHist SD
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PricesHist ED ON
    ED.Product = SD.Product AND
    ED.Price = SD.Price
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PricesHist LD ON
    LD.Product = SD.Product AND
    LD.Price <> SD.Price AND
    LD.EndDate < SD.StartDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PricesHist LMD ON
    LMD.Product = SD.Product AND
    LMD.Price = SD.Price AND
    LMD.StartDate > ISNULL(LD.EndDate, '1900-01-01') AND
    LMD.StartDate < SD.StartDate
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.PricesHist MD WHERE MD.Product = SD.Product AND MD.Price <> SD.Price AND MD.StartDate BETWEEN SD.StartDate AND ED.EndDate) AND
    LMD.Product IS NULL
GROUP BY
    SD.Product,
    SD.Price,
    SD.StartDate
ORDER BY
    SD.StartDate
```

Comment: @Tom H. would you mind for helping me on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378663/mysql-querying-aggregate-of-non-overlapping-dates ?